# Every closed bounded subset of $l_1$ has an extreme point.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

$$ l_1 = \{(x_n) : x_i \in \mathbb {R}, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i| < \infty \}$$

Let A be a closed bounded subset of $l_1$. Then there exist $x, y \in A$ such that $\|x-y\|=$ diam A = R (say) . If x or y is an extreme point of A then we are done. Otherwise $x=\lambda x_1+ (1-\lambda)x_2$, $y=\alpha y_1+ (1-\alpha)y_2$ where $\lambda, \alpha >0$ and $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in A$. Now

$R= \|\lambda x_1+ (1-\lambda)x_2 -\alpha y_1- (1-\alpha)y_2  \|$

$=\| \lambda \alpha (x_1-y_1) + \lambda (1-\alpha) (x_1-y_2) (1-\lambda)\alpha (x_2 - y_1) + (1-\lambda)(1-\alpha) (x_2-y_2)\|$

$\leq  \lambda \alpha \|(x_1-y_1)\| + \lambda (1-\alpha) \|(x_1-y_2)\| (1-\lambda)\alpha \|(x_2 - y_1)\| + (1-\lambda)(1-\alpha) \|(x_2-y_2)\|$

$\leq R$

This shows that $\|x_1-y_1\|= R$, $\|x_1-y_2\|= R$, $\|x_2-y_1\|= R$, $\|x_2-y_2\|= R$.

If one of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ is extreme point then we are done otherwise continue the same process as above.

But can we say this process will terminate by an extreme point?
I cannot prove this statement. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change $\sum x_i <\infty$ to $\sum |x_i| <\infty$ in the first line.

Comment: The first step itself is wrong. You need compactness to say that $x$ and $y$ exist.

Comment: Right. So is it correct that every closed bounded (non-compact) subset of $l_1$ has an extreme point ? Because in case of compact subsets we can conclude it from Krein Milman theorem.

Comment: Yes Krein Milman theorem requires compact convex set. But if A is compact but not convex then we will consider its closed convex hull. Closed convex hull of a norm compact subset of a Banach space is again norm compact ( Diestel, Sequence and series in Banach spaces, exercise 1, page 4). Extreme point of closed convex hull of A = Extreme point of A

Comment: $l_1$ space has Radon Nikodym Property and RNP has an equivalent definition in geometry of banach spaces that every closed bounded subset of X has an extreme point. So $l_1$  should satisfy the same. But the problem is how to show that....